# Вычислить матрицу миноров Python (не используя numpy)

Tags: python, матрицы

Нужно найти все миноры матрицы. Через рекурсию нашел определитель матрицы, но найти матрицу миноров не получилось. Вот код:

```
def minor(A, i, j):
    M = copy.deepcopy(A)
    del M[i]
    for i in range(len(A[0]) - 1):
        del M[i][j]
    return M
```

Функция для нахождения определителя матрицы(это работает исправно):

```
def det(A):
    n = len(A[0])
    if n == 1:
        return A[0][0]
    signum = 1
    determinant = 0
    for j in range(n):
            determinant += A[0][j]*signum*det(minor(A, 0, j))
            signum *= -1
    return determinant
```

А это попытка найти матрицу миноров, но безуспешно:

```
def minor_matrix(A):
    n = len(A[0])
    mm = []
    signum = 1
    determinant = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        mm.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            mm[i].append(0)

    if n == 1:
        return A[0][0]

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            determinant += A[i][j] * signum * minor_matrix(minor(A, i, j))
            signum *= -1
            mm[i][j] = determinant
            return determinant

    print("\n Матрица миноров: ")
    for r in mm:
        print(r)

    return mm
```

Comment: `determinant += A[i][j] * signum * minor_matrix(minor(A, i, j))` а потом `mm[i][j] = determinant` - кажется, здесь проблема, Вы же в `determinant` храните сумму нескольких миноров (вернее, даже алгебраических дополнений), а в элементах `mm` должно быть по одному минору

Comment: Т.е. надо написать что-то вроде `mm[i][j]=minor_matrix(minor(A, i, j))` и потом `determinant += A[i][j] * signum * mm[i][j]`